# UICollectionview changes selection/disabling selection while scrolling - iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, boolean, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm populating data on uicollectionview cell and selecting and deselecting, everything works perfect but when I start scrolling sometime selection is not there sometimes selection changing with the cell. Below is the code, help much appreciated.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      cell = (BYOCollectionCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CVCCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
      cell.vSelectionView.hidden = YES;
      cell.vSelectionView.backgroundColor = customLightGreenColor;
      [self makeRoundElement:cell.vSelectionView forLabel:nil withCorner:8.0f withBorder:0];

      pizzaInfo *pizzainfo= [[pizzaInfo alloc]init];
      pizzainfo = [_lstDishCollection objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];  
      if (pizzainfo._bIsSelected)
      {
           cell.vSelectionView.hidden = NO;
      }
      else
      {
           cell.vSelectionView.hidden = YES;
      }
      //label customization 
      return cell;
 }
```

**DidselectItem**

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      cell = (BYOCollectionCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CVCCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
      pizzaInfo *pizzaInfoCellData = [_lstDishCollection objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
      byoPizzaInfo = [_lstDishCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      if ( pizzaInfoCellData._bIsSelected)
      {       
           cell.vSelectionView.hidden = NO;
           pizzaInfoCellData._bIsSelected = NO;
           [self._byodelegate deltaDeSelection:pizzaInfoCellData];
      }
      else
      {
           cell.vSelectionView.hidden = YES;
           pizzaInfoCellData._bIsSelected = YES;
           // deltaSelection:(pizzaInfo *)selectedItem
           [self._byodelegate deltaSelection:pizzaInfoCellData];
           if (self._IsNotifiable) {            
                [self showView];            
           }
      }
      [_vCVC reloadData];
 }
```

More over `collectionViewCell` is inside `tableViewCell.`

Comment: your code is poorly indented. It makes it very hard to help you since understanding your code will take a lot of time now.

Answer (score 2):

In your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you have already added condition for hide and show the selected view so you need to change your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` like this

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     pizzaInfo *pizzaInfoCellData = [_lstDishCollection objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
     if (pizzaInfoCellData._bIsSelected)
     {       
          [self._byodelegate deltaDeSelection:pizzaInfoCellData];
     }
     else
     {
          [self._byodelegate deltaSelection:pizzaInfoCellData];
     }
     pizzaInfoCellData._bIsSelected = !pizzaInfoCellData._bIsSelected
     [_vCVC reloadData];
}
```

**Note:-** Class name always start with uppercase latter so it is batter if you change your class name `pizzaInfo` with `PizzaInfo`, its suggestion for good coding guidelines.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But it's still while scrolling selection is going off. [self._byodelegate deltaDeSelection:pizzaInfoCellData] / [self._byodelegate deltaSelection:pizzaInfoCellData];  with these line of code am removing/adding object from/to array, that's why am using if else block. can you please check again.